# Nifi Clustering: Embedded Zookeeper setup issue

Tags: apache-nifi

I have followed the NiFi clustering steps mentioned in [NiFi admin guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html). But  the NiFi nodes are not forming a working cluster with embedded zookeepers. Am I missing something? Please help.

The configuration in zookeeper.properties is as follows. The 192.168.99.101 is the localhost IP address where NiFi is running and listening on port 9090:

```
clientPort=2181
initLimit=10
autopurge.purgeInterval=24
syncLimit=5
tickTime=2000
dataDir=./state/zookeeper
autopurge.snapRetainCount=30
server.1=192.168.99.101:2888:3888
```

The configuration pertaining to Zookeeper in nifi.properties is as follows:

```
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.start=true
nifi.state.management.embedded.zookeeper.properties=./conf/zookeeper.properties
nifi.zookeeper.connect.string=192.168.99.101:2181
nifi.zookeeper.connect.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.session.timeout=3 secs
nifi.zookeeper.root.node=/nifi
nifi.zookeeper.auth.type=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeHostFromPrincipal=
nifi.zookeeper.kerberos.removeRealmFromPrincipal=
```

Comment: No one will be able to tell what is wrong without seeing your configuration.

Comment: @BryanBende - The configuration files were the default ones which were bundled into the NiFi Docker. I had made changes only to specific configuration properties as mentioned in clustering setup docs linked in my question. I had not pasted all the configs as that would make the question too verbose. Anyways, I have pasted the relevant portions in my question now. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error message in the log? If yes, update your post with them. BTW, have you set the `myid` file in ZooKeeper's `dataDir`?

Answer (score 4):

Following the detailed Zookeeper based NiFi clustering steps as documented in these articles helped: [Pierre Villard on NiFi clustering](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/08/13/apache-nifi-1-0-0-cluster-setup/) and [Elton Atkins on NiFi clustering](https://mintopsblog.com/2017/11/12/apache-nifi-cluster-configuration/).

Also, following Matt Clarke's advise regarding using [dedicated external zookeepers](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/82213/nifi-cluster-startup-exception-cluster-is-still-in.html) instead of embedded zookeepers helped.

Documenting what helped me just in case it helps someone else who struggles with similar problem in near future.